# Partial Converse to "Pushout of a cofibration is a cofibration"

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences

$\require{AMScd} \newcommand{\RP}{\mathbb{RP}}$
I want a converse of this fact specialized to the case where I am pushing out a map BY a fibration:

I.e., if I am given a diagram

$ \begin{CD}
E_1 @>i>> E_2 \\
@V\text{fibration}Vp_1V @Vp_2V\text{fibration}V\\
B_1 @>cofibration>j> B_2 \\
\end{CD}$,

does it follow that $i$ is a cofibration?

I am doing this to prove that the inclusion $F_p E \to F_{p+1} E$ is a cofibration,for the filtration used in the serre spectral sequence.

Edit

---

When I made this question, I had the misconception that every pushout square was also a pullback square(I will conveniently blame it on a student lecturer in my class who said "this pushout square" when he was referring to a square that was just a pullback square.).  Thus I did not realize that I needed to further specify that the above square be a pullback square.  I am embarrassed to admit it.  But I created a new question with this new condition.

Comment: This claim is plausible since $E_1 \to E_2$ is also an inclusion - a necessary condition for a map to be a cofibration.  I am looking again through the proof that the pullback of a fibration is a fibration, to see if I can use it.  After all the proof that the pullback of a cofibration is a cofibration is a dualized argument of this, and when I have both of these objects, somehow I might be able to use something....  Thats all I know for now.  Come back later if I think of something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In full generality, it's not true, even if $E_1 \to E_2$ is an inclusion. Take $E_1 \to E_2$ to be your favorite inclusion that's not a cofibration and let $B_1 = B_2 = *$.  Then $E_i \to B_i= *$, $i = 1, 2$, are fibrations (every space is fibrant), the identity $B_1 \to B_2$ is a cofibration, and the diagram commutes, but $E_1 \to E_2$ is not a cofibration by construction.

However, if $E_1$ and $E_2$ are CW complexes, then it's probably true, since every (cellular) inclusion of CW complexes is a cofibration.

---

**EDIT:** The example I gave above ignores the "pushout" condition.  If we assume (per OP's comment) that the square is a pullback, then the answer seems to be affirmative.  See theorem 14.1 in Strom's *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory*.

Comment: Thanks.  What if I add the requirement that $E_1 \to B_1$ is the pullback fibration of $E_2 \to B_2$?  (this counterexample won't work since the identity map is always a cofibration).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this.  You are the reason this world is a great place.