# bottom map of pullback square is cofibration $\Rightarrow$top map is cofibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$\require{AMScd} \newcommand{\RP}{\mathbb{RP}}$
I am trying to show that for a given fibration $E \xrightarrow{p} B$, and a cell structure $\{B_n\}$ on $B$ that , that $p^{-1}B_n \to p^{-1}B_{n+1}$ is a cofibration.  I am trying to deduce it from a more general fact(that I hope is true).

Question:

Let $E_1$ be the pullback of a fibration $E_2 \xrightarrow{p_2} B_2$ along a cofibration $j$:

$ \begin{CD}
E_1 @>i>> E_2 \\
@V\text{fibration}Vp_1V @Vp_2V\text{fibration}V\\
B_1 @>cofibration>j> B_2 \\
\end{CD}$,

Does it follow that $i$ is a cofibration?

Note:  This question comes from 
my previous quetsion [Partial Converse to "Pushout of a cofibration is a cofibration"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858125/partial-converse-to-pushout-of-a-cofibration-is-a-cofibration).   I did not realize that I needed to further specify that the above square be a pullback square so I created this question.

Comment: I edited my answer to your previous question.  The answer is yes (but does not follow from formal arguments); see theorem 14.1 in Strom's *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory*.

Comment: i think, if $p^{-1}B_n \to p^{-1}B_{n+1}$ is a closed inclusion, it is a cofibration automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume that $B_1 \to B_2$ is an inclusion(This is satisfied for the cofibration $B_p \to B_{p+1}$ that you are interested in).  The only thing I need to use is   $B_1 \to B_2$ is a cofibration $\iff$ $(B_2,B_1)$ an NDR Pair.  Suppose that its given by the homotopy $h: B_2 \times I \to B_2$ and $u: B_2 \to I$.

For the obvious lift $E_2 \times 0 \to E_2$ 
$\require{AMScd} \newcommand{\RP}{\mathbb{RP}}$
the diagram 
$ \begin{CD}
 E_2 \times 0 @>>> E_2 \\
@VVV @Vp_2VV\\
E_2 \times I  @>(h:B_2 \times I \to B_2)\circ p_2>> B_2 \\
\end{CD}$,
has a solution $H: E_2 \times I \to E_2$.  Its a 5 second mental exercise to check that $(E_2,E_1)$ is an NDR pair given explicitly by the homotopy $H$ and $u \circ p: E_2 \to I$.  Therefore $E_1 \hookrightarrow E_2$ is a cofibration.

Comment: What if $p_2$ is a Serre fibration? Do you need to assume $E_2$ to be a CW complex, or can you avoid it?

Comment: I think you also need to prove that $H$ does not move $E_1$, but it doesn't seem to be true.