# Pullback of a good pair by a fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology

A pair $(X, A)$ is a *good pair* (as defined in Hatcher) if $A$ is a deformation retract of some neighborhood $N$ in $X$. Suppose $\pi : Y \to X$ be a fibration, and let $B = p^{-1}(A)$. Hatcher claims in his proof of Theorem 5.3 (see page 530 [here](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/ATch5.pdf)) that $B$ is a deformation retraction of $\pi^{-1}(N)$ in the weak sense, meaning that the deformation retraction need not fix the subspace $B$. His argument is that, given a deformation retraction of $N$ onto $A$, by the homotopy lifting property this lifts to a weak deformation retraction of $\pi^{-1}(N)$ onto $B$. He uses this to conclude that the inclusion map $B \hookrightarrow \pi^{-1}(N)$ is a homotopy equivalence. However, I can't see why the lifted homotopy necessarily ends at a retraction $\pi^{-1}(N) \to B$; namely, it may not fix the subspace $B$. Would someone be able to clarify his argument?

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858517/bottom-map-of-pullback-square-is-cofibration-rightarrowtop-map-is-cofibration), which is more general. However, I have the same issue with the answer given; I don't see why the lift $H$ would fix $E_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no immediate reason for a lift to necessarily end at a retraction $\pi^{-1}(N)\rightarrow B$. However, when Hatcher says "where the latter deformation retraction is in the weak sense that points in the subspace need not be fixed during the deformation", this (perhaps counter-intuitively) includes the end value. In other words, all he claims is that there is a homotopy $H\colon\pi^{-1}(N)\times I\rightarrow\pi^{-1}(N)$ such that $H_0=\mathrm{id}_{\pi^{-1}(N)}$, $H_t(B)\subseteq B$ for all $t\in I$ and $H_1(\pi^{-1}(N))\subseteq B$. The lift clearly does satisfy this and this in fact suffices to conclude that $B\hookrightarrow\pi^{-1}(N)$ is a homotopy equivalence, which I leave as an exercise. Two alternatives:

1. You could alternatively argue that if the bottom map in such a fibration pullback square is a weak homotopy equivalence, then so is the top map (this follows e.g. by the naturality of the long exact fibration sequence). The argument in Hatcher only needs a weak homotopy equivalence (plus, a weak homotopy equivalence between CW-complexes is a homotopy equivalence anyway).
2. If you additionally assume that $A\hookrightarrow N$ is a closed cofibration (which is the case in Hatcher's application), you can in fact argue that $B\hookrightarrow\pi^{-1}(N)$ is a strong deformation retraction. Indeed, in that case $B\hookrightarrow\pi^{-1}(N)$ is a closed cofibration too (this is the subject of the linked question and while the argument there is indeed incomplete, it can easily be completed, see [Theorem 12 in Strøm's *Note on Cofibrations II*](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN35397434X_0022?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B141%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D)). Then, applying the "covering homotopy extension property" (which is proven originally in Strøm's *Note on Cofibrations I* and also covered in many algebraic topology texts), you get a homotopy $\pi^{-1}(N)\times I\rightarrow\pi^{-1}(N)$ covering the homotopy $\pi^{-1}(N)\times I\rightarrow N\times I\rightarrow N$ and extending the constant homotopy $B\times I\rightarrow B$, i.e. a strong deformation retraction of $\pi^{-1}(N)$ onto $B$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! At the end did you mean to write $N \times I \to N$ instead of $\pi^{-1}(N) \times I \to N \times I \to N$?

Comment: Not quite, you have a deformation retraction $N\times I\rightarrow N$ of $N$ onto $A$ and you pre-compose this with the map $\pi^{-1}(N)\times I\rightarrow N\times I$ that is the projection in the first factor and the identity in the second factor. This is the thing you lift through the fibration $\pi^{-1}(N)\rightarrow N$ with initial value the identity of $\pi^{-1}(N)$ in order to get the homotopy $H\colon \pi^{-1}(N)\times I\rightarrow\pi^{-1}(N)$.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense.